# how to put two or more ndarrays in a single array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

everyone.
I have a list with two sublists like this:

```
my_list = [['Hamburg', 'Hanover', 'Leipzig'], ['Leipzig', 'Nuremberg']]
```

I am using `np.array(my_list, dtype=object)`
but the result is :

```
result = [list(['Hamburg', 'Hanover', 'Leipzig']) list(['Leipzig', 'Nuremberg'])]
```

But, I want to have a result like :

```
Correct_result = [['Hamburg' 'Hanover' 'Leipzig'], ['Leipzig' 'Nuremberg']]
```

Could you please let me know what should i do and how can i solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The 2 lists have different sizes.  You can't get the desired result.  Why did you think you could?

Comment: You cant create a numpy array with a list of lists with uneven sizes.

Comment: Voting to close due to lack of clarity

Comment: I don't understand your question. As you said, you already have a list: my_list = [['Hamburg', 'Hanover', 'Leipzig'], ['Leipzig', 'Nuremberg']]. However, you want your result : Correct_result = [['Hamburg' 'Hanover' 'Leipzig'], ['Leipzig' 'Nuremberg']] ?? Is it the same as your original list my_list?

Answer (score 0):

as Duong said, your `my_list`and `Correct_result` are already the same.

If you meant for your end result to be a numpy array of numpy arrays, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np


my_list = [['Hamburg', 'Hanover', 'Leipzig'], ['Leipzig', 'Nuremberg']]
Correct_result = []
for sub_list in my_list:
    Correct_result.append(np.array(sub_list, dtype=object))
Correct_result = np.array(Correct_result, dtype=object)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer what OP is asking for. This just iterates over the list of lists and recreates the same.

Comment: I see you've editted OP's question, but you've done so wrong. Your edit still shows that his original my_list is the same as Correct_result. You also state that you cannot create a numpy array with a list of lists with uneven sizes. Running my code snippet, you'll see it is possible. While we are awaiting clarification from OP, let's not be too hasty about downvoting potentially correct answers.

Comment: I have not edited any content. please click on the edit and see what I have done. I have only added code blocks.

Comment: Also, please print and add the result for `Correct_result`

Comment: Check the `Correct_result.shape`

Comment: If an question doesnt make sense, please clarifty in comments rather than answering. Plus I dont downvote. I comment to help people correct their mistakes.

Comment: Akshay, as you can see from my account, I have 43 reputation, which is less than the 50 rep needed to post comments on questions. Instead, I attempted to answer it, and also leave a comment in my answer.

Comment: "Which is NOT a 2D array". I never said it was a 2D array. OP also never said he wants a 2D array.

Comment: Thats ok, but people on SO either provide feedback via comments or via downvotes. I dont see why that should bother you when you are making an assumption and answering the question.

Comment: Because I feel the feedback is based on nothing. I made an attempt to answer OPs question, and you (or anyone) downvotes it, not because the answer is wrong, but because the ambiguity of OP's question makes it difficult to determine which answer is actually right.

Comment: Thats a matter of opinion i guess. In anycase, please feel free to answer and contribute completely, but do take feedback constructively. If you dont agree with it, then thats your choice and right as well.

Comment: Just to clarify my reason. `[list(['Hamburg', 'Hanover', 'Leipzig']), list(['Leipzig', 'Nuremberg'])]` is the same as `[np.array(['Hamburg', 'Hanover', 'Leipzig']), np.array(['Leipzig', 'Nuremberg'])]`. What OP wants is `[['Hamburg' 'Hanover' 'Leipzig'], ['Leipzig' 'Nuremberg']]` as a numpy array, which somewhat indicates that they are looking for a 2D array and not a 1D array containing lists or other numpy arrays. Hope that makes my reasoning clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help and reply. But the main thing that I want is "Remove the list" from the result. If you see the Correct result you can see that I removed the "list" from it. Because I save my results to .csv file and in there it appears. Now with your answer "numpy" appears instead of "list".

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed a list of lists to a NumPy array, it's normal that you see 'list' at the beginning of each dimension, it gives you a hint that you have made a NumPy array from a python list.